# Problema al visualizar la ruta de una app en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy comenzando a aprender Django

escribi estos pedazos de codigo para configurar todo para renderizar la vista

la carpeta de la app se llama playground

en la misma el archivo urls.py tiene esto

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.first_f)
]
```

en el archivo views.py esto:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
# Create your views here.


def first_f(request):
    return HTTPResponse('Hello world')
```

en el archivo urls.py esto:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls'))
]
```

y en settings.py esto

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'playground'
]
```

cuando corro django y pongo localhost:8000/playground/hello para renderizar la funcion, me arroja este error:

```
NameError at /playground/hello/
name 'HTTPResponse' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'HTTPResponse' is not defined
```

Comment: No has importado `HTTPResponse`, en su lugar importaste `HttpRequest`

Comment: la acabo de importar y me arroja que:    return HTTPResponse('Hello world')
NameError: name 'HTTPResponse' is not defined @Christian

Comment: Es por que el nombre está mal, el nombre correcto es `HttpResponse` (mira las mayúsculas y minúsculas)

Comment: ahora si, gracias @Christian debio ser que mientras escribia la palabra me hizo una sugerencia y se la puse pensando que era la adecuada y me agarro todo en mayuscula